# How to read the network requests for a extension in puppeteer

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

I am launching chrome with my extension using the command

```
google-chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222  --disable-setuid-sandbox --no-sandbox --load-extension=dummyextension --ignore-certificate-errors
```

Generally i would see all the requests made by my extension when i enable developer mode and click on inspect views. Is there a way to read those network requests with help of puppeteer.

I am trying to read the network requests like below:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

 (async () => {
   const browser = await puppeteer.connect({browserWSEndpoint :'ws://localhost:9222/devtools/browser/e27e967f-711' });
   const page = await browser.newPage();

   await page.goto('https://github.com');
   await page.setRequestInterception(true);


    page.on('request', request => {
      request.continue(); // pass it through.
    });

    page.on('response', response => {
      const req = response.request();
      console.log( response.status(), req.url());
    });

})();
```

But i see the requests only for the github page but not the requests made by my extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try (from [debugging tips](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer#debugging-tips))

```
# Basic verbose logging
 env DEBUG="puppeteer:*" node script.js

 # Debug output can be enabled/disabled by namespace
 env DEBUG="puppeteer:*,-puppeteer:protocol" node script.js # everything BUT protocol messages
 env DEBUG="puppeteer:session" node script.js # protocol session messages (protocol messages to targets)
 env DEBUG="puppeteer:mouse,puppeteer:keyboard" node script.js # only Mouse and Keyboard API calls

 # Protocol traffic can be rather noisy. This example filters out all Network domain messages
 env DEBUG="puppeteer:*" env DEBUG_COLORS=true node script.js 2>&1 | grep -v '"Network'
```